# Dedicate physical NIC to a virtual machine

Tags: vmware-workstation

I am running VMware Workstation 16.1 Pro on a Windows 10 Pro tower.  The tower has 2 network cards.  I want to configure networking like this:

**NIC 1**:  I want to give one of my virtual machines this network card all by itself.  It should use it just as if it were a real machine on the external network (getting its IP address from the external network DHCP server, not from Workstation Pro).

**NIC 2**:  I want this network card to be used for all the rest of my virtual machines in typical fashion e.g. guests get 192.x IP address from Workstation Pro).

Here is what I have tried and it does not work:

[image]

[image]

[image]

My goal is to let this 1 virtual machine get it's IP dynamically (DHCP) from the external network.  How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bridged is the appropriate setting for what I understand your desired outcome to be. Apparently, per [VMWare's documentation](https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-Workstation-Pro/16.0/com.vmware.ws.using.doc/GUID-D05850F8-E850-4086-A735-5C84C72D007C.html), VMnet1 cannot be used for this purpose:

> By default, virtual switch VMnet0 is mapped to a bridged network. You can create a custom bridged network on virtual switches VMnet2 to VMnet7. On Windows, you can also use VMnet19.

There are some acceleration paths that enable higher performance, but full hardware passthrough typically requires a Type 1 Hypervisor, where the hypervisor installs on the bare metal, and all (other) operating systems exists as guests. This is largely incompatible with using the system as a local user.

Comment: @relayman357 - You should have submitted an answer instead of editing the solution into the answer.  Questions should never contain the solution

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to add a second network adapter to the virtual machine's settings.  For whatever reason, once I did this I could set it to `Custom(VMnet0)` and it would stick this time.  Here is what my setup looks like now:

[image]

Also, here is a look at the network adapters under Network Connections on the virtual machine (Windows Server 2008 R2):

[image]

p.s.  I've marked Amorphous's answer correct because without it I would have been stuck I think.